# Java library for full n-ary trees in the style of quadtrees

Tags: java, tree, quadtree

I'm looking for a Java library to manipulate full n-ary trees in the style of quadtrees. Actually, i just need it for n=9, but i reckon the extra generality is worthwhile for others. It's for a GIS i'm developing wherein 2D regions are partitioned into elements on a 3^k x 3^k grid (instead of a 2^k x 2^k grid when using quadtrees). In particular, i'd like the  library to have efficient methods for adding nodes, traversing the tree, and doing range searches. Do you know of such a library?

I couldn't find one in my Google searches, but i want to double check with you all for its existence before making my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for KD Tree implementations.